# Laravel object data overwritten?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, eloquent, laravel-3

I've got an application built in Laravel 3 and I've run into a very strange bug. I have a model with two datetime fields: `start_time` and `end_time`. I also have the timestamps enabled for this model so there are also `created_at` and `updated_at` datetime fields.

I have a controller action which handles the editing/updating of objects within this model. When running this action, every other time you change the `end_time` field, the `start_time` field is overwritten with the minutes and seconds of the `updated_at` field. I know this sounds crazy but here are some things I've done while debugging.

First I switched from using the `fill_raw($input)` function and started using manual assignment in case there was something weird going on there.

```
    $object->start_time = $start_time;
    $object->end_time = $end_time;
    $object->save();
```

I've also added `echo` statements all throughout the action to make sure the value wasn't being changed at any point, including one that prints the value stored in the object after the `save()` function is called. Every time the value is as expected. However, sometime between the end of the action where the page is redirected and when the page reloads, the value is being changed in the database.

At this point I'm thinking it must be something weird on the database end since I know that for instance in PHPMyAdmin when you're manually adding a row it will auto-fill datetime fields with `NOW` when they're set to `NOT NULL` but not filled in. But that being said, I've already double-checked that the field isn't empty as has the correct value. I'm at a dead-end here and could really use another perspective.

EDIT:
[Here's](http://pastebin.com/aPdSYnCt) a link to a copy of the controller action in question. Again I'll point out that there are `echo` statements throughout the action which I have used to verify that the input data is correct and not being altered in any unexpected ways throughout the entire action. The problem I'm encountering only appears after the action has run.

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you unless you post some code.

Comment: If you understand what I wrote you'll realize that I've provided as much code as is really needed to understand the problem. But for the sake of brevity and cooperation I'll post the pared down version of my code.

Comment: Oh well, I'm obviously too dim to help you then. Good luck.

Comment: @DavidMyers You should include the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtablename`

Comment: @rsanchez I just did that and found the problem. The start_time field had the ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP option set for some reason. Submit an answer for the bounty.

Comment: The reason is due to MySQL default handling of the timestamp column type. More information about it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22860351/6543983). A simple fix is to make the timestamp column `->nullable()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A column that updates to the current time is consistent with it having an `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` clause.

Issuing a `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourtablename` can confirm it.