# MySQL column type "TIMESTAMP" implicitly includes "NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I've just spent a couple of hours tracking down this bug. Given the following SQL:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS db;
CREATE DATABASE db;
CREATE TABLE db.tbl (t1 TIMESTAMP) ENGINE=INNODB;
SHOW CREATE TABLE db.tbl;
```

The last line shows me:

```
'CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
  `t1` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'
```

Where on earth does the `NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` come from? I didn't write any of that, and I very much do not *want* any of that, and I'm kinda lost for words that MySQL would make such a presumption.

Do I have some insane obscure configuration option turned on/off? Is this default behavior? It is a bug? In any case, how do I make MySQL behave sanely?

Comment: You probably want `datetime` instead of `timestamp`. A `timestamp` is for versioning records and the default behaviour is updating that column if the record is updated.

Comment: @juergend thanks. [The MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) does not make it at all clear that that is what the `TIMESTAMP` type is intended for. Whoever wrote that documentation should be taken outside and shot.

Comment: I suppose you're aware of it but docs say «The TIMESTAMP data type offers automatic initialization and updating to the current date and time» and links to [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp-initialization.html). Writer does not deserve more than a short sentence.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I just stumbled upon this behaviour and I read the docs, but I didn't expect an *offer* being imposed on me ;-)

Answer (score 18):

In MySQL **5.6.5** there are several updates regarding this initialization, you can see on this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html) (Automatic Timestamp Properties Before MySQL 5.6.5).

If you're using MySQL <= **5.6.5**, in order to ignore this initialization you need to set the DEFAULT value to 0 or NULL with NULL allowed.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
(
    field1 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0,
    field2 TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
```

If you're using MySQL >= **5.6.6**, there is parameter called [explicit_defaults_for_timestamp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp) which is disabled by default. You can enable this setting or set the DEFAULT value to 0 or NULL, same approach for previous MySQL versions.

If you're using MySQL >= **8.0.2**, then [explicit_defaults_for_timestamp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp) is **enabled** by default. This disables the non-standard behaviour (thankfully). Also, MySQL generates a warning when you disable this setting. So, for instance, if you don't define DEFAULT value for a `TIMESTAMP` column, it is automatically set to `NULL`.

Comment: It is worth mentioning, that MySQL only adds these defaults for the _first_ TIMESTAMP column in the table, even before 5.6.5

Answer (score 3):

Thos are default values which are being used even if not explicitly stated in the CREATE statement. If you want to avoid both, use `t1 TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0` or `ts1 TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL`

**Update**

Prior to MySQL 5.6.5 you could only use `TIMESTAMP` in case you wanted to have column that is automatically updated when row is changed. Unfortunately this functionality was limited to MyISAM and isn't available on InnoDB tables.

MySQL 5.6.5 allows this with `DATETIME` as well. See other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column) on this site for more details

Comment: Thanks, though neither of those options look like what I want in my case: I want `TIMESTAMP NOT NULL` without a default value and without any crazy update trigger. How do I specify that?

Comment: Those are the only options.

Comment: @jameshfisher It night help to know what exact feature of TIMESTAMP that you need to use is missing from DATETIME. Perhaps we can think of an alternative.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario no, `DATETIME` is fine. It just annoys me that `TIMESTAMP` has these arbitrary restrictions, sadistically unintuitive specification options, and that the documentation is so unclear.

Comment: I edited the answer to explain key difference between `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP`.