# mysql and Python: does not allow two timestamp columns

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm having issues with Python, MySQL and creating a table with two timestamp columns.

Executing the following SQL through Python and using MySQLDB:

```
CREATE TABLE test_db.test_with_two_datetime_columns (
    `first_datetime_field` TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `second_datetime_field` TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I get the error `(1067, Invalid default value for 'first_datetime_field')`, whereas I can easily fire of the following equal command in the `MySQL` CLI:

```
$ mysql -h localhost

> CREATE TABLE test_db.test_with_two_datetime_columns (
      `first_datetime_field` TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
      `second_datetime_field` TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Similarly through Sequel Pro the above command executes fine.

So I'm guessing the problem is with `MySQLDB` (akak. `MySQL-Python`), but that seems very weird

I'm using `MySQL 5.6.17`, `MySQL-Python 1.2.5` and `Python 2.7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using an idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22860449/1362628, by changing the default value to `null` and allow the entry to be `null`.

```
CREATE TABLE test_db.test_with_two_datetime_columns (
    `first_datetime_field` TIMESTAMP(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `second_datetime_field` TIMESTAMP(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB""")
```

And now it works fine. The problem though, is that none of these fields can partake in a `primary key`, as they can contain `null`.

---

*Update*

It turns out that using `SELECT @@session.sql_mode` I found that the wrapper code on MySQLDB was setting `sql_mode` to `TRADITIONAL`. `TRADITIONAL` expands to `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, STRICT_ALL_TABLES, NO_ZERO_IN_DATE, NO_ZERO_DATE, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO, TRADITIONAL, NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`, where `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` and `NO_ZERO_DATE` makes the above error appear.  In the long run though, I am more for the above solution, with an absent value represented as null.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a couple of issues here.

My guess is that MySQLDB doesn't recognize the integer 0 as a valid value for a column of type DateTime or Timestamp. IMHO, MySQL shouldn't either, but it does. You can change that behavior at the server level. See [NO_ZERO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date).

If I were in your shoes, I'd try something along these lines.

```
CREATE TABLE test_with_two_datetime_columns (
    `first_datetime_field` TIMESTAMP(6) not null default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `second_datetime_field` TIMESTAMP(6) not null default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    primary key (first_datetime_field, second_datetime_field)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

These defaults are effectively identical to the integer 0 in this context. One alternative is to default both columns to the minimum value of a timestamp, '1970-01-01 00:00:01'. Another is to default one column to current_timestamp. (Not both columns; MySQL regards that as an error.)

Personally, I don't like timestamps that are "all balls". "All balls" is a timestamp oddity--lexically, it's not in the defined range of of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC. But you have to find your own comfort level with that.

Comment: Yup, I tried that, but with no success. I still get an (1067, "Invalid default value for 'first_datetime_field'") error. Defaulting to current_timestamp is not really an option, because if we have an error in our code, a default timestamp could hide that.

Comment: Do you get that error with defaults of '1970-01-01 00:00:01'? Maybe a bug report to MySQLDB is called for.

Comment: Yup, that I get. I'll make a bug report to MySQLDB.