# Custom timestamp copies updated_at on $model->save()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, timestamp

I have a table and related model that has a custom timestamp. The migration is set like this:

```
Schema::create('tests', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamp('expire_at');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And I have set up my Model like so:

```
class Test {
    protected $dates = [
       'expire_at'
    ];
}
```

When I try to update the name field only, it sets the `expire_at` field as same as `updated_at` field rather than simply not changing it.

```
$test = Test::find(1);
$test->name = "Changed Value";

// Until here, the expire_at timestamp has its true value
// but on save(), it changes expire_at to updated_at time.

$test->save();
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong with the `protected $dates` usage?

Comment: You might need to make your `expire_at` column nullable (with `$table->timestamp('expire_at')->nullable()`). You can check if your database has a default value of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or similar for the expire_at column, which would be setting a value when you leave it null.

Comment: @TravisBritz Oh yes, you are right - when I check the mysql, it shows `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for the column. Is `->nullable()` the right way to do overcome it?

Comment: Cool, I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the column nullable (or remove the default value, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`):

```
$table->timestamp('expire_at')->nullable();
```

Comment: More information about why the `->nullable()` modifier is needed can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/q/22860351/6543983