# Why TIMESTAMP return NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

"TIMESTAMP" return NULL in table

MySQL 8.0.17

```
CREATE TABLE towary(
    id SERIAL,
    nazwa VARCHAR(255),
    przyjecie TIMESTAMP
);
INSERT INTO towary (nazwa) VALUES ('AAA');
```

Comment: Because you haven't defined any default value for the column having `timetamp` datatype

Comment: Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22870825/2469308 in the duplicate marked question

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting a row with three columns.  The first has a "default" value because it is `serial`, so it gets assigned.

The `timestamp` column has no default value, so it is assigned `NULL`.

If you want it to default to the current timestamp, you need to assign a default value:

```
CREATE TABLE towary(
    id SERIAL,
    nazwa VARCHAR(255),
    przyjecie TIMESTAMP DEFAULT current_timestamp
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=022ac772ba0b1dda6bc45db640ada9e4) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Is it change from version 5.6?
Because on video course i see exactly the same above text and timestamp return correct result (date).

Comment: przyjecie TIMESTAMP default now() - it's worked, but if it is optimal (clean) solution?

Comment: @GeriGeri It is changed from version 8.0.2 onwards. Check: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp